# Laravel 5 Pivot Table Extra Field

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

What I’m trying to do is when a new candidate is created an extra field is automatically populated in the joining pivot table with a random sting.

Here is my pivot table:

Result Table (pivot)

```
id  cert_number candidate_id    qualification_id
1   ?           17              2
2   ?           17              1
3   ?           57              1
```

So in my candidate controller I have:

```
public function store(CandidateRequest $request)
{
    $candidateInput = Input::get('candidates');


    foreach ($candidateInput as $candidate)
    {
        $candidate = Candidate::create($candidate);

        $candidate->centre()->attach(Auth::user()->centre);

        $qualification_id = $request->input('qualification_id');

        $candidate->qualification()->attach($qualification_id);

        $cert_number = Str::random(10);

        $candidate->qualification()->attach($cert_number);

    }

    return redirect('candidates');
}
```

It adds the centre_id and qualification_id perfectly but it won’t pull though the random sting into the cert_nubmer field.

In my Candidate model I have

```
public function result()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Result')->withTimestamps();
}

public function qualification()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Qualification', 'Results', 'candidate_id', 'qualification_id')->withPivot('status','cert_number','partial_claim')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and in my result model:

```
public function candidate()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Candidate')->withTimestamps();
}

public function qualification()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Qualification');
}
```

Can anyone see where Im going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output if you do: `dd($cert_number)`?

Comment: "nbRLEUFuqA" So it is generating a random string just not passing it along

Comment: This is the error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vault3`.`results`, CONSTRAINT `result_qualification_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`qualification_id`) REFERENCES `qualifications` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `Results` (`candidate_id`, `created_at`, `qualification_id`, `updated_at`) values (412, 2015-11-16 16:41:19, A1WzVHh1OX, 2015-11-16 16:41:19))

Comment: Sounds to me like the problem is with the `qualifications` and a relationship somewhere.. But, that might have been because you're trying to do something weird with the data. What happens if you remove trying to attach the cert?

Comment: Also (Haven't really used `attach`) but does it not imply that there is a relationship between the two? The first two `candidate`, `qualification` are inserting into the table because you have defined their relationship, BUT I can't see where you have defined the `certificate`? If this field is NOT a relational field, i.e. there is no relationship then attach might be a bad way to insert the cert_id to the database

Comment: It goes through fine. Only no cert_number (obviously)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95257/discussion-between-phorce-and-0w3n86).

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Could you recommend another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach does not work like that.

Let me take out two lines of code:

```
$candidate->qualification()->attach($qualification_id);
$candidate->qualification()->attach($cert_number);
```

You are trying to add the $cert_number as a qualification_id, which is why it fails. When you do this, how is Laravel supposed to know that the second line ($cert_number) is an extra pivot column? It doesn't. You have two lines of code that are exactly the same so you can't expect Laravel to know that the second line should do something different.

When you want to insert extra data into other pivot columns, you need to pass them as an array in the second argument. Something like this:

```
$candidate->qualification()->attach($qualification_id, ['cert_number' => $cert_number]);
```